# Vagrant Error: "missing required parameter 'token'"

Tags: vagrant, atlas

I have a box on Vagrant Atlas:

https://app.vagrantup.com/devopskatas/boxes/learningvm

I'm trying to run it on a client PC that is not logged into Atlas.  I get the following error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

Atlas push:
* Missing required configuration parameter 'token'. This is required for
Vagrant to securely communicate with your Atlas account.

To generate an access token, run 'vagrant login'.
```

I don't want users to have to log in to download this box.  How do I resolve this error without logging in?

Answer (score 0):

I was running an old version on my laptop.  I ran `vagrant box remove devopskatas/learningvm` then re-ran `vagrant init devopskatas/learningvm`.  All is well.